# Return single column with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

```
 public string GetNameBySSN(string SSN)
 {
    var results = from c in Clients
                  where c.ClientSSN.Equals(IRRCNumber)
                  select c.FirstName;
    //return results.ToString();
 }
```

I want to return a single column value with Linq and not sure if there is way to do a quick easy return. I commented section of code that I know does not return the value and if enumerate through collection I can get the value but wondering if a better way was around.

I do understand that Linq is Set based and that it has no upfront means know that the
result is set with a single member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`results.FirstOrDefault();`

This way will not throw an exception, FYI. Where as @Mehrdad will.

Answer (score 6):

```
return results.First().ToString();
```

Other possible variants:

**.First()** returns the first item and throws an exception if no item exists. It ignores all other items.

**.FirstOrDefault()** returns the first item if exists and returns the default value of the result type if nothing exists. It ignores all other items.

**.Single()** returns the only item if the collection contains **exactly one** item and throws an exception otherwise.

**.SingleOrDefault()** is like **.Single()** but returns the default value of the result type instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: If c.FirstName is a string you dont need the ToString.

Comment: Of course. This was mentioned in the commented code and I replicated it for that matter.