# Issue with filtering DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `DataTable` `dtsupp` that looks like this:

```
Supplier | Code
---------+-----
supp1    | 001
supp2    | 002
supp3    | 003
```

I want to return a string by calling

```
SELECT Code WHERE Supplier = mySupp
```

My code looks like this:

```
var code = from row1 in dtsupp.AsEnumerable()
           where row1.Field<string>("Supplier") == supp
           select row1.Field<string>("Code");
```

When I run this code I get an error

> system.data.enumerablerowcollection`1[system.string]'

Can someone guide me as to what I have done wrong? I am quite new to LINQ.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return single column with Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981625/return-single-column-with-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it is actually returning `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>` and probably you are directly trying to read that as `string` thus the error.

Simply add `FirstOrDefault` to get the first matching value:-

```
var supp = (from row1 in dtsupp.AsEnumerable()
           where row1.Field<string>("Supplier") == supp
           select row1.Field<string>("Code")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or if there may be multiple `Supplier` with same `Code` then let the query as it is and iterate it with `foreach` loop (to actually run the query) like this:-

```
 foreach (var item in supp)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(item);
 }
```

Comment: I put my whole statement in Parenthesis, but clicking . does not expose the First() or FirstOrDefault() functions. As a result I get the error: 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I was missing a namespace. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to execute query. Add `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()`, `ToList()` or so on based on your condition. These methods will execute your query immediately.

```
var code = (from row1 in dtsupp.AsEnumerable()
           where row1.Field<string>("Supplier") == supp
           select row1.Field<string>("Code")).First();
```

Due to the deferred execution, the iterator will not execute until the CLR calls the the methods I wrote in my first sentence or uses the **`ForEach`** method to iterate through.

Look for Deferred and Immediate Execution in Linq. [(for example look at that article)](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/6DJI160714-Difference-between-Deferred-execution-and-Immediate-execution.html)

Comment: I mentioned this in my other comment, but I put my whole statement in Parenthesis, but clicking . does not expose the First(), FirstOrDefault() or any of those functions you listed. As a result I get the error: 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I was missing a namespace. It works now. Thanks

Comment: @nerdalert Glad to help.